# Selecting and Deselecting segment on UISegmentedControl?

Tags: ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I've added a segmented control as the right bar button item of my navigation bar. The control has two segments and I'm attempting to use the control as bar button items. So I was wondering haw can I deselect a selected segment once the user preses it. I've already tried setting the selectedSegmentIndex property to -1 when the action method is called but that is preventing the segment from even being highlighted. Any idea on how can can get the segments to behave like bar button item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do `segmentedControl.momentary = YES;` during setup or if using IB, select the `Momentary` checkbox in the `Attributes Inspector`.